# Problems with UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Publisher";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"This Is A Very Very Long String";
```

which results with the following look: (only first table row is relevant)

[image]

As it appears, the detail text is overlapping the "Publish" title so both strings are truncated.
What I wish is to have the "Publish" title neverc being truncated as follows:

[image]

Is this possible using UITableViewCellStyleValue1? I saw many posts suggesting to create a custom cell but is it really the only way?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Any luck solving this problem?

Comment: Still not... What intresting is the iPhone simulator shows Publisher perfectly. I need to test on iOS 4.0 device as well...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property for cell's labels to YES and `minimumFontSize` property to an appropriate value. If it does not help - it seems you should use custom cells indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and post results

Answer (score 0):

I realize some time has passed since this post, so there have probably been updates to this functionality from the SDK. What I've found in Xcode v4.1 is UITableViewCellStyleValue1 now does what you wished. The  textLabel.text doesn't truncate.

Using UITableViewCellStyleValue2 will truncate the title. [Where the doc suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW42)

> it functions as a heading or caption for the important information in
>   the more prominent, left-aligned detail text label.